# Call api with curl and TLS 1.2 Two Way with public certificates of entities

Tags: rest, ubuntu, curl, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I am currently calling a service which requires mutual authentication with curl and ubuntu, currently
I have the following certificates `certRoot.cer`, `certSub.cer`, `domain.com.cer` and `pubkey.pem`, to add the certificates to the path `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` transform them all to a format pem and i made the call:

```
curl -v \
--key /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
-u "user:password" \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"info":"data"}' \
https://endpoint.com:4445/api/path
```

This call itself is correct and returns the following information:

```
*   Trying ip...
* Connected to endpoint.com (ip) port 4445 (#0)
* found 136 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 536 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: endpoint.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=CO,ST=STATE,L=DATA,O=DATA,OU=Sistemas,CN=endpoint.com
*        start date: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 14:42:57 GMT
*        expire date: Thu, 02 Sep 2021 14:42:57 GMT
*        issuer: C=CO,ST=DATA,L=DATA,L=ADDRESS,O=DATA,OU=Gerencia de Sistemas,CN=DATA Sub CA Terceros
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> POST api/path HTTP/1.1
> Host: endpoint.com:4445
> Authorization: Basic dXNycHJ1X2Jpb2NyZWRpdDpQc123YmExMjM7
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 920
> 
* upload completely sent off: 920 out of 920 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Tue, 06 Apr 2021 21:37:21 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
< Content-Length: 234
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /api/path
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host endpoint.com left intact
```

but at the moment in which the call is verified from the api side, it indicates that the certificate was not sent and rejects the connection, I imagine that is why it returns the error 403 (forbidden).

I have also tried to do it by passing the certificates directly, but it returns this error:

```
curl -v \
--key pubkey.pem \
--cert domain.com.cer \
-u "user:password" \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"info":"data"}' \
https://endpoint.com:4445/api/path
```

In this case the answer is the following:

```
*   Trying ip...
* Connected to domain.com (ip) port 4445 (#0)
* found 136 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 536 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* error reading X.509 key or certificate file: Error in parsing.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error reading X.509 key or certificate file: Error in parsing.
```

I clarify that all this also happens through a vpn and the connection to this vpn is already ok, if anyone has any idea how I can solve this problem I thank you very much, it can be with using any language or terminal client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this call successfully I did it with python, then I leave the code that I use:

```
import socket
import ssl
 
host_addr = 'domain.com'
host_port = 4445
server_sni_hostname = 'domain.com'
server_cert = '../DESTINATION.cer' #CERTIFICATE OF DESTINATION, IN PEM FORMAT ( -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...... -----END CERTIFICATE----- )
client_cert = '../CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE.cer' #CUSTOMER CERTIFICATE, IN PEM FORMAT ( -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...... -----END CERTIFICATE----- )
client_key = '../CUSTOMER_PRIVATE_KEY.key' #CUSTOMER PRIVATE KEY, IN PEM AND PKCS8 FORMAT (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ....... -----END PRIVATE KEY-----)
 
basicAuthHeader = 'dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==' #USER:PASSWORD >> BASE64
 
method = 'POST /path/of/service HTTP/1.1\r\n'
headers = 'Host:'+host_addr+'\r\nContent-Type:application/json\r\nAuthorization:'+basicAuthHeader+'\r\nAccept:application/json\r\n\r\n'
body = '{"data":"string","data1":"string","data2":"string","data3":"string","data4":"string"}'
 
 
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile=server_cert)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=client_cert, keyfile=client_key)
 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn = context.wrap_socket(s, server_side=False, server_hostname=server_sni_hostname)
conn.connect((host_addr, host_port))
 
 
print("SSL established. ")
print("Sending:")
conn.send(bytes(method+headers+body, 'utf-8'))
 
print("Receiving")
received = conn.recv(36000)
print(received)
 
 
print("Closing connection")
conn.close()
```

I hope it will be of help to you in the future, for me it was a long task until I reached the solution.